# Will killing Python script that called shell processes also kill the shell processes?

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, kill-process

If I have some code like this in the file this_script.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python", "another_script.py"])
```

and I call

```
python this_script.py
```

and kill the process while it is running, will it kill the subprocess?

Edit: I tested this, and if this_script is killed, the subprocess continues running. Is there a way to make sure that the background process dies when the main Python process does?

Comment: Why not give it a try?

Comment: The answer may be different on different platforms, so as @TymoteuszPaul suggests, you should try it yourself to be sure how it acts on your platform.

Comment: I tested it, continues running when main process is killed (this is on CentOS). Is there a way to make sure the subprocess dies when the main process dies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  you can catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `SystemExit` and make sure to `kill` the subprocess.

```
from subprocess import Popen

try:
    p = Popen(args)
    p.wait()  # wait for the process to finish
except KeyboardInterrupt,  SystemExit:
    p.kill()
    raise
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that `Popen()` runs asynchronously. In other words, the main Python process will almost immediately exit and you now have the subprocess running in the background. To fix it, you could add `p.wait()`. in the `try` block, or change `except ..` to `finally` ... Not sure which the OP wants...